# UIView animate with delay blocks UI interactions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

The documentation for UIView animateWithDuration says that during the animation all user interactions are blocked. But I'm wondering if it also blocks during the pre-animation delay.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:) says

> "During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for
>   the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are
>   disabled for the entire application.) If you want users to be able to
>   interact with the views, include the
>   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options
>   parameter."

But when I give a significant delay (let's say 1 second), it blocks the UI during that second as well. I wouldn't guess that to be the case as the documentation for the delay parameter says:

> "The amount of time (measured in seconds) to wait before beginning the
>   animations. Specify a value of 0 to begin the animations immediately."

Key words there are *before beginning* the animations while the note about blocking user interaction talks about *during an animation*.

However, my application doesn't update the UI during the pre-animation delay. Does the delay block UI interactions as well or is my UI blocked for another reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that the UI is blocked during the delay before animation begins. To be honest, I was surprised.

Comment: Is there away around this?